# What is the purpose of clrp2.js in youtube.com?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, youtube

If you check the network in youtube.com,

It try to request clrp2.js from this url `Request URL: https://meetsit.website/cu/clrp2.js`
 at first thing to load. Even before requesting for font.

What is this script for? I cannot find anything while googling around about it. And why it's even more important than loading font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be from either an extension on your browser or perhaps it is from youtube itself. but as for order of loading, this isn't exactly out of the ordinary. as little_monkey said earlier, when you have a slow network or even a slow device, it is best to load the parts of the website that are needed first, before cosmetics like fonts.

Comment: Chrome Extention makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an external JS file that youtube uses for the site javascript.

Also, for people with slow internet, you would want the site essentials to load in first, not the font which is for cosmetic purposes.

Comment: is this fact or opinion?

Comment: The answer is not correct for downloading essentials part, 
if you mean Critial Rendering Part, but it's usually hardcoded to html,
if you at least audit youtube  than it's obvious what is the essential script to generate view. This clrp2.js is too small to be that essential script.